# Not terminating but stopping cloud build agent

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity supports creating VMs in the cloud for running builds. It can also terminate instance after it is idle for defined period of time.

Is it possible not to terminate but shutdown the instance and to start it again when needed?

Answer (score 1):

If your BA is a VM on Azure then I was able to achieve this by using Azure Automation account (There is a free version).

Basically, you trigger WebHooks for 2 runbooks you import from the gallery - StartAzureV2VM & StopAzureV2VM. The gallery can be found in "Automation Account-> Runbooks -> Browse Gallery"

Then on your TeamCity server you just periodically run some powershell which  monitors the build queue on Teamcity and trigger appropriate webhook (with some timeouts etc.).

Here is the script I'm using, feel free to amend it to your needs:

https://gist.github.com/milanio/b300f23883afa9c6288f9365dfb98252

Comment: Good idea, I can start EC2 instance, if queue has the corresponding build.